# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection'

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have a project that I am trying to compile with mono to run on ubuntu. Runs well and good on windows, compiling for mono with `xbuild` works fine, but when I try to run it from the server I get the following error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection' from assembly 'Npgsql, Version=3.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
```

at

```
NpgsqlConnection _connection = new NpgsqlConnection();
```

Npgsql version 3.2.1.0 is present, so I'm not sure why this error appears.

---

I do the following steps

- Mono x86 cmd > `xbuild /p:Configuration=Release D:\Dropbox\MonoServer\MonoServer.csproj`
- Transfer all files to server
- PuTTy `mono MonoServer.exe`

I had to manually transfer `System.Data` to the server as well, since for some reason that is not not included and would result in:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

After I did that I get the Npgsql error. Npgsql is mono compatible by the way.

I don't know what other information could be useful here. I appreciate any help!

Comment: this normally happens when you have a `using` in your header but do not manually add the reference to the project also this could be an invalid or version issue if it adds an entry into the .Config file.. have you checked to make sure references are being deployed or consumed properly

Comment: @MethodMan The project successfully compiles in mono and visual studio, so there is no `using` that is not being referenced.
My .config files look as following: http://pastebin.com/CawXA94R

I am also pretty sure all references are deployed correctly, but I will check again. I transfer all files generated by xbuild + the System.data

Comment: there are settings on the assembly / reference that will determine if the dll gets copied over or not.. make sure the `CopyLocal` property for the dll's are set to `true` for the appropriate one.. running locally is a whole lot different than when you execute and or launch an application outside of your development machine / local machine `GAC` or otherwise

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks for the reply, I switched all CopyLocal to true which initially solves the problem of System.Data not being needed to be copied manually, but the Npgsql problem is still present. I tried transferring all files to a windows server and it runs fine there (ie outside of development machine) but running it in mono on ubuntu is still not working. :/

Comment: Additionally, I created a new project only referencing Npgsql.dll (and it's dependencies) and I have the same problem there.

Comment: @Ezzy Did you finally came up with solution?

Comment: @AgainPsychoX Sorry, I don't remember what project this was for nor if I solved it. I know it's not much help.