# System.TypeLoadException: Could not find method due to a type load error

Tags: c#, postgresql, unity-game-engine, mono, npgsql

I'm getting an error while I'm trying to run my dll on the game server and I'm stuck af:

> [2021-08-06 15:36:59.000 +02:00] [ERROR] [Guardian] System.TypeLoadException: Could not find method due to a type load error at ...

Notes:

- I'm using the nuget package Npgsql 5.0.7
- I'm using a modding framework called Exiled which use a separate folder to load dependencies.

Comment: @Lloyd Hey, thx for the reply, honnestly i have no idea to fix this issue however i found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792868/system-typeloadexception-could-not-load-type-npgsql-npgsqlconnection, but it's not working

Comment: This could be the result of mixing incompatible package versions or similar - in any case it's not possible to know without a minimal project sample.